# How to troubleshoot "Internet Server Error 500"

Tags: php

I have a single page, called `index.php`, with:

```
echo "testing"
```

I'm getting "Internal Server Error 500" and there's no error log. How can I troubleshoot the error?

Comment: make error reporting on

Comment: @DevsiOdedra u mean "display_errors" inside the php.ini?

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  

in your index.php file after `<?php `

Answer (score 0):

It is server error which is relative to server service like apache or ngnix. This erro we can not debug in php debug technique becuse it is server related error to find server log file from /var/log/nginx.log (for ngnix server).

Please refer below link for more information.

https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938